# Unable to select bones individually (Blender 2.80)

Tags: rigging, bones

I recently installed an older version of Blender on a random computer in my house because my notebook died and I have to use my father's old computer. These days I've been trying to study rigging characters and I've tried rigging a model, but I can't select individual bones. It always selects all or nothing, and if I click many times on one point of the bones (I think it is the main bone), the bone selection changes to another bone.

Link with a video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YfmEMGyaMft0Y92lIgQQMC6qlpZgul4t/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for the description, I'm new to Blender.

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You seem to be switching into Pose mode rather than Edit mode. If you just want to edit the individual bones, press Tab to toggle between Object and Edit mode. Pose mode is used to actually pose the bones once you have everything set up. and you can toggle that mode with Ctrl-Tab.

Comment: I tried to switch with the keys but it doesn't work ;-;

Comment: Works fine here using Blender 2.80 so it sounds as if it may be a problem with the computer you're using.

Comment: Sad, I can do something about it?

Comment: Try installing on another "random" computer? :^)